# How do I fix a TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

Tags: python, python-3.x

My function is supposed to take as an input a list that contains a list of numbers. Each number list is supposed to represent the grades a particular student received for a course. For example, here is an input list for a class of four students:

[[95, 92, 86, 87], [66, 54], [89, 72, 100], [33, 0, 0]]

My function is supposed to print one per line, every student’s average grade. I can't assume that every student as the same number of grades.

This is what I have so far:

```
def avg(grades):
    for average in grades:
        return sum(grades) / len(grades)
```

But when I tested it out by typing `avg([[95, 92, 86, 87], [66, 54], [89, 72, 100], [33, 0, 0]])` it shows this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    avg([[95, 92, 86, 87], [66, 54], [89, 72, 100], [33, 0, 0]])
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 3, in avg
    return sum(grades) / len(grades)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

The solution should be:

```
90.0
60.0
87.0
11.0
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution :

```
students_results = []
def avg3(students):
    for student in students:
        students_results.append(sum(student) / len(student))
    return students_results

arr = [[95, 92, 86, 87], [66, 54], [89, 72, 100], [33, 0, 0]]
print(avg3(arr))
```

Result : [90.0, 60.0, 87.0, 11.0]

Answer (score 2):

You need to do `sum(average)` and `len(average)`, with `average` not `grades`:

```
def avg(grades):
    for average in grades:
        print(sum(average) / len(average))
avg([[95, 92, 86, 87], [66, 54], [89, 72, 100], [33, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: This is the closest solution to my problem but it only outputs to the average of the first list. The output for this is 90 but it should be: 90.0, 60.0, 87.0, 11.0.

Comment: The other answers are better. The return inside the for loop is likely to be a problem.

Comment: @Mish Edited mine

Answer (score 2):

```
grades= [[95, 92, 86, 87], [66, 54], [89, 72, 100], [33, 0, 0]]

def avg(grades):
    for average in grades:
        print(sum(average) / len(average))
    return 
avg(grades)
```

Output:

```
90.0
60.0
87.0
11.0
```